# Starting and stopping Bootstrap carousel with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use a Bootstrap carousel to cycle through a series of D3 charts and tables, showing performance data for a specific team. After a complete cycle, the team input is toggled and the charts are reloaded for the newly-selected team.

The issue that I'm running into is that the data can take as long as 20 seconds to get to the client. As a result, the carousel often cycles before the first slide can load.

What I figured I'd do is wait until the data is available to start the carousel in the first place, and then essentially pause it at the end of a cycle, restarting it once the new data has loaded. To do so I'm calling `$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: '10000' })` when the data becomes available. This works fine on initial page load. However I need to pause the carousel before requesting data for the next team, and I can't seem to figure out how to do so. It appears as though setting `$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: false })` has no effect.

Something to keep in mind is that I'd like to retain the carousel's manual slide controls and 'hover' pause behavior in between cycles.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE (sample code):**

*Original technique:*

Markup:

```
<div
  id="carousel"
  class="carousel slide"
  data-ride="carousel"
  data-interval="30000"
  data-pause="hover"
 >
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      ...
```

Javascript:

Upon completion of a cycle:

```
toggleTeams()
Session.set 'loading', true // show loading overlay
```

After each data reload:

```
Session.set 'loading', true // show loading overlay
if ticketSubscriptionHandle.ready() // wait for data to be ready
  Session.set 'loading', false // hide loading overlay
  drawCharts() // redraw charts
```

*Latest technique:*

Markup:

```
<div
  id="carousel"
  class="carousel slide"
 >
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      ...
```

Javascript:

Upon completion of a cycle:

```
carousel = $('.carousel')
carousel.detach() //remove the carousel from the DOM to stop the cycle while data loads
toggleTeams()
Session.set 'loading', true // show loading overlay
```

After each data reload:

```
Session.set 'loading', true // show loading overlay
if ticketSubscriptionHandle.ready() // wait for data to be ready
  if isFirstLoad
    $('.carousel').carousel(interval: '2000') // start the carousel
    isFirstLoad = false
  else
    $('.container-fluid').append(carousel) // drop the carousel back in
  Session.set 'loading', false // hide loading overlay
  drawCharts() // redraw charts
```

Even with this technique it appears as though the carousel is changing after I remove it from the DOM. If I throw a debugger in at removal I can see that the `.active` slide is slide 1 of 5, yet when it gets reinserted it's at slide 2, 3, or sometimes 4. This carousel is something else...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Look this (carousel \ Methods)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#carousel-methods)

```
.carousel('cycle')
```

Cycles through the carousel items from left to right.

```
.carousel('pause')
```

Stops the carousel from cycling through items.

```
.carousel(number)
```

Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an array).

```
.carousel('prev')
```

Cycles to the previous item.

```
.carousel('next')
```

Cycles to the next item.

Comment: I've tried several combinations of these. My guess at this point is that they can't be used to modify a carousel once it's been initialized. Just above the code you copied are the following lines 

`.carousel(options) Initializes the carousel with an optional options object and starts cycling through items.`

The initialization works fine. It's interrupting that carousel cycle that's the problem. I could always resort to creating a new carousel each time...

Comment: Apologies - it turns out I was overthinking this. I'd seen some examples showing that the syntax for setting pause to 'hover' is `.carousel({ pause: 'hover' })` and unpausing the carousel os `.carousel({ pause: 'false' })` so I was trying to pause the carousel by calling `.carousel({ pause: 'true' })` or `carousel({ pause: 'true' })`, when in fact the correct syntax is, as @wit_peter and the docs point out, `.carousel('pause')`.

Answer (score 0):

Stop:

```
$("#carouselExample").attr('data-interval', '0');
```

Start:

```
$("#carouselExample").attr('data-interval', '9000');
```